# C# How to ignore the invalid columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, sqlbulkcopy

I created the following `SqlBulkCopy` to insert data from Excel into a SQL Server  database. If I have invalid column in my Excel, for example `second_name` instead of `last_name`, my program will ignore that column while the data from other columns will be added to the database.

However, this did not happen using the below code. I got an error message

> No value given for one or more required parameters

and no data was inserted into database. Could someone help me to fix this problem? Thank you

```
string myexceldataquery = "select person_id,first_name,last_name,gender from [Sheet1$]";

try
{
    string sexcelconnectionstring = @"provider=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + excelFilePath +
             ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 12.0;hdr=yes;\"";

    con.Open();

    OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
    OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);

    oledbconn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "person";

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("person_id", "person_id");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("first_name", "first_name");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("last_name", "last_name");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("gender", "gender");
    }

    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);

    dr.Close();
    oledbconn.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("File imported into sql server.");
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This question makes your previous question make a lot more sense. So given that you asked about putting column names into comboboxes last time i.e.  building a UI that maps "these column names" to "those column names", I'm curiuous why this code appears to contain no dynamic mappings at all? Why are your mappings hardcoded?

Comment: Why are you putting the ColunMappings in the for loop?.  It should be before the for loops. When results are more than one row you are adding duplicate mappings which is creating errors.  Code will work if you have only one row of results.